# Como faço para remover acentos em uma string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, acentuação

Eu tenho uma `string`

```
áéíóú
```

Que eu quero converter para

```
aeiou
```

Como eu removo os acentos? Preciso para guardar no banco de dados como uma URL.

Comment: Também respondido no SO em inglês: [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/249087/1316620)

Comment: Ao invés de remover os acentos, por que você não codifica os caracteres acentuados como parte da URL?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Você pode usar esta função:

```
public static string RemoveAccents(this string text){   
    StringBuilder sbReturn = new StringBuilder();   
    var arrayText = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).ToCharArray();
    foreach (char letter in arrayText){   
        if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(letter) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            sbReturn.Append(letter);   
    }   
    return sbReturn.ToString();   
}
```

Fonte: http://www.ninjacode.com.br/post/2011/08/10/Retirar-acentos-de-strings-C.aspx

Comment: Isto não apaga também símbolos de unidades monetárias, dígitos e vários símbolos de pontuação?

Answer (score 36):

Você também pode fazer a leitura de todos os caracteres que está na variável `comAcentos`, e dado um `Replace` no parâmetro que foi passado na função, ou seja, é substituído as letras que estão `comAcentos` pelas de `semAcentos` e retorna o novo texto.

```
public static string removerAcentos(string texto)
{
    string comAcentos = "ÄÅÁÂÀÃäáâàãÉÊËÈéêëèÍÎÏÌíîïìÖÓÔÒÕöóôòõÜÚÛüúûùÇç";
    string semAcentos = "AAAAAAaaaaaEEEEeeeeIIIIiiiiOOOOOoooooUUUuuuuCc";

    for (int i = 0; i < comAcentos.Length; i++)
    {
        texto = texto.Replace(comAcentos[i].ToString(), semAcentos[i].ToString());
    }
    return texto;
}
```

Comment: Algumas palavras em espanhol e outras linguagens e também e na linguagem web, utilizam `ñ` e `Ñ`. Poderia acrescentar essa letra também para tornar a lista mais completa.

Answer (score 34):

Usando LINQ fica bem prático:

```
public static string RemoverAcentuacao(this string text)
{
    return new string(text
        .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
        .Where(ch => char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        .ToArray());
}
```

### O que são `NormalizationForm.FormD` e `UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark`

Isso é uma forma de representar a string original de forma que marcas como acentuação, cedilha, entre outras, sejam separadas em caracteres distintos: o caractere base, que é a letra, e o caractere da marcação. O caractere de acentuação, neste caso é chamado de `NonSpacingMark`, ou seja, marcador sem espaço, significa que é um marcador que não ocupa nenhum espaço, e será aplicado ao caractere anterior.

Usando o LINQ podemos remover estas marcações, deixando apenas os caracteres base, sem as marcações e construímos uma nova string a partir desses caracteres.

Answer (score 26):

```
public static string RemoverAcentos(this string texto)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(texto))
       return String.Empty;

   byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-8").GetBytes(texto);
   return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}

string nome = "João Felipe Portela";
string nomeSemAcentos = nome.RemoverAcentos();
```

Comment: Só uma diga para melhorar a leitura do código.
A condição else não é necessária, visto que estamos a retornar uma string empty se o texto for vazio ou nulo.

Comment: Antes tarde do que nunca!

Answer (score 19):

Existe esse método que utilizo para remover acentuação:

```
public static string RemoverAcentos(string texto){

    string s = texto.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int k = 0; k < s.Length; k++)
    {
        UnicodeCategory uc = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(s[k]);
        if (uc != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            sb.Append(s[k]);
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Uma alternativa as respostas dadas acima é instalar o seguinte nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MMLib.Extensions/

então você podorá remover os acentos da seguinte forma:

```
var str = "áéíóú";
str = str.RemoveDiacritics();
```

Answer (score 13):

O código de página (codepage) **Greek (ISO)** pode fazer isso

Informações sobre este codepage podem ser obtidos no retorno do método `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings()`. Veja mais [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding(v=vs.110).aspx).

Greek (ISO) tem o codepage **28597** e nome **iso-8859-7**.

Vamos ao código... \o/

```
string text = "Você está numa situação lamentável";

string textEncode = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7"));
//result: "Voce+esta+numa+situacao+lamentavel"

string textDecode = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(textEncode);
//result: "Voce esta numa situacao lamentavel"
```

Então, escreva essa função...

```
public string RemoverAcentuacao(string text)
{
    return
        System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(
            System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(
                text, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")));
}
```

Observe que `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")` é equivalente a `Encoding.GetEncoding(28597)`. O primeiro busca pelo nome, o segundo pelo codepage do Encoding.

Outras opções pode ser vistas no [Stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net):

Answer (score 0):

Em QTcreator

```
QString GerCorrida::removeAccentuation(QString text)
{
    QString with = "ÄÅÁÂÀÃäáâàãÉÊËÈéêëèÍÎÏÌíîïìÖÓÔÒÕöóôòõÜÚÛüúûùÇç";
    QString withOut = "AAAAAAaaaaaEEEEeeeeIIIIiiiiOOOOOoooooUUUuuuuCc";
    for (int i = 0; i < with.size(); i++)
    {
        text = text.replace( with[i], withOut[i] );
    }
    return text;
}
```