# Existe alguma função para retirar os acentos em strings c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma string "Acadêmico", por exemplo, e preciso retornar essa string como id de um div no html, e para isso quero retorná-la sem o acento.

Comment: Neste link apresenta varias soluções, veja se algumas delas consegue te ajudar

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-remover-acentos-em-uma-string