# Caracteres especiais em StreamWriter com Encoding.ASCII C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou escrevendo em um arquivo via StreamWriter usando a codificação Encoding.ASCII. Apareceu uma situação em que necessito escrever a letra "Ç". Só que se eu tentar fazer isso, no arquivo sai o caractere "?".

Neste caso, necessito usar essa codificação (não posso utilizar UTF8). Há alguma forma que eu possa tratar esse caractere e fazer aparecer corretamente no arquivo?

Um trecho do exemplo do código:

```
StreamWriter streamArquivo = new StreamWriter(caminhoArquivo, false, Encoding.ASCII);
streamWriter.WriteLine("COBRANÇA");
```

Tentei ver algo relacionado ao código da letra "Ç" em byte, etc mas o problema continua. Será que há como fazer isso?

Comment: Porque não pode usar UTF-8? O que mais não pode usar?

Comment: @bigown não posso utilizar esta codificação pois é um arquivo utilizado na comunicação com outro sistema. Se eu utilizar UTF-8 por exemplo, e eu abrir o arquivo no editor do MSDOS, aparecem alguns caracteres como "¬" que atrapalham a comunicação.Por isso optei por ASCII, porém agora preciso que essa palavra saia "Ç"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O *encoding* mais simples que resolve seu problema é o Latin1 ([veja tabela](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). No lugar do ASCII usaria:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
```

ou

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Encoding.cs).

Dependendo do seu caso pode ter que usar o 850 ou 860.

Se não puder usá-lo, a solução é converter o texto [tirando os acentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2/101), tem perda de informação, mas é a única solução que sobrou.

Comment: Ótimo!! Tenho um caso que usando o Encoding [UTF8Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.utf8encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) também não reconhecia alguns caracteres, sendo o "Ç" meu principal problema. No meu caso resolveu com o `Encoding.GetEncoding(850)`.

Comment: funcionou aqui!! Valeu!

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito aqui.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022: Resolveu pegando RTF do ItemContact.Body do Outlook 365 para colocar no C# Winforms RichTextBox. Valeu!