# Busca lenta ignorando acentos

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma lista de objetos e estou fazendo uma busca por título.

Utilizo o *Normalizer* para fazer a comparação ignorando acentos:

```
public static boolean containsIgnoreCaseAndAccents(String haystack, String needle) {
    final String hsToCompare = removeAccents(haystack).toLowerCase();
    final String nToCompare = removeAccents(needle).toLowerCase();

    return hsToCompare.contains(nToCompare);
}

public static String removeAccents(String string) {
    return ACCENTS_PATTERN.matcher(Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD)).replaceAll("");
}
```

E a busca:

```
for(Object o : allObjects){

            if(o.getTitle()!=null && containsIgnoreCaseAndAccents(o.getTitle(), text)) {
                searchObjects.add(o);
            }
}
```

O texto eu pego da minha *EditText*. Funciona, porém há um *delay* nesta comparação, e a busca fica levemente travada, dando um *delay* ao digitar cada letra.

Existe alguma forma de fazer esta comparação de modo mais rápido?

Answer (score 3):

Por cada "titulo" que verifica está sempre a remover os acentos do texto a comparar.

Remova apenas os acentos do texto uma vez e use-o em cada comparação com o "titulo"

Use uma classe para fazer as comparações:

```
public classe IgnoreCaseAndAccentsComparator{

    private String text;  

    IgnoreCaseAndAccentsComparator(String text){

        this.text = removeAccents(text).toLowerCase();
    }

    public boolean contains(String text){

        this.text.contains(removeAccents(text).toLowerCase());
    }

    //Se quiser pode adicionar outros métodos de comparação

    public static String removeAccents(String string) {
        return ACCENTS_PATTERN.matcher(Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD)).replaceAll("");
    }
}
```

Use assim:

```
IgnoreCaseAndAccentsComparator comparator = new IgnoreCaseAndAccentsComparator(text);

for(Object o : allObjects){

    if(o.getTitle()!=null && comparator.contains(o.getTitle())) {
        searchObjects.add(o);
    }
}
```

Se a pesquisa for feita enquanto o texto é digitado o desempenho pode ser melhorado se usar um "delay" entre cada chamada ao método de forma a que ele não seja chamado por cada letra introduzida mas apenas após haver uma pausa na introdução.

<sub>**Nota:** Apenas tentei optimizar o seu código sem questionar a forma como é feita a remoção dos acentos, que possivelmente também pode ser optimizada.</sub>

Comment: Eu testei. Ficou levemente mais rápido, porém o dalay ainda é presente. Eu resolvi o problema de outra forma, vou submeter a resposta, talvez você possa fazer comentários de melhorias.

Answer (score 0):

Meu problema era por ter que fazer a pesquisa enquanto o texto era digitado. Como era uma pesquisa digitada, não são muitas opções de letras acentuadas. Utilizei a esta resposta (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2626/1385) como base e fiz meu método para substituir as strings acentuadas.

Ficando assim:

```
public static String removeAccent(String lowerCaseString)
{
    String withAccent = "äáâàãéêëèíîïìöóôòõüúûùç";
    String withoutAccent = "aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuuc";

    for (int i = 0; i < withAccent.length(); i++)
    {
        lowerCaseString = lowerCaseString.replace(withAccent.charAt(i), withoutAccent.charAt(i));
    }
    return lowerCaseString;
}
```

A performance ficou boa e funciona para os acentos do teclado do Android, até porque as buscas irão ser feitas em português.