# Serializar XML tratando caracteres especiais

Tags: c#, xml

Eu gero um XML de Nfse, porém eu preciso tratar os caracteres especiais, exemplo: `´^~Ç` etc, eu serializo ele desta forma:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GerarNfseEnvio));
FileStream arquivo = new FileStream("E:\\NFSe-" + "RPS" + 
       numero.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0') + 
           ".xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
xsn.Add("", "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd");

ser.Serialize(arquivo, gerar, xsn);
arquivo.Close();
```

Em vez de tratar campo por campo, tem alguma maneira de mudar quando for criar o `XML` pois, Assim trato tudo de uma vez?

**EDIT**

Eu gero um xml por exemplo com tags, por exemplo

```
<Discriminacao>Relógio Henry-250\s\nDescrição 62-29\s\n</Discriminacao>
```

Não pode ter acentos, Ç etc. Deveria sair desta forma:

```
<Discriminacao>Relogio Henry-250\s\nDescricao 62-29\s\n</Discriminacao>
```

Eu quero tratar o xml todo, pois são muitos campos.
Esta linha é quando serializo o `xml`:

```
ser.Serialize(arquivo, gerar, xsn);
```

Queria saber se é possível antes de serializar, ou ao serializar, retirar os caracteres especiais.

**EDIT**

Eu passo os campos desta forma

```
gerar.Rps.InfDeclaracaoPrestacaoServico.Tomador.Endereco.Endereco = 
    tomador.EnderecoCobranca.Trim();
```

Porém não queria colocar a função em cada campo, pois são muitos, queria saber se tem alguma forma de fazer isso ao gerar o xml, ao serializar ou carregar ele e substituir, algo do tipo.

Comment: Disponibiliza na sua pergunta uma cópia do arquivo! um Exemplo não conseguir entender

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei para esclarecer.

Comment: Mariana precisa gerar esses dados sem acentuação e/ou caracteres especiais, por qual motivo?

Comment: Quando vou assinar/enviar o XML, ele não aceita se tiver caracteres especiais.

Comment: No próprio site tem como remover isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-remover-acentos-em-uma-string olha só são vários exemplos

Comment: Os dados vem em um classe ou uma lista dessa classe?

Comment: Os dados vem de uma classe, e de uma lista de classe, são dois tipos. Vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Eu precisava entender o que é realmente o que você tem em informação

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu gero um xml, e preciso que ao passar os dados, tire os caracteres especiais, pois se eu fizer por campo, por campo, vai dar muito trabalho, pois NF-e possuem vários campos, então queria saber se tem uma forma de fazer isso ao gerar o xml.

Comment: Você tem que exemplificar o dado antes de gerar o XML pra que possamos dar um norte! assim fica complicado eu saber qual é o dado, talvez o problema é antes e possa ser resolvido mais fácil

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu crio um xml, passando os dados através de um schema, para serializar, que seria o xml da NFse, para gerar eu informo o valor para cada campo, em vez de utilizar replace em cada campo, eu queria ver se tem alguma forma de fazer, seja ao serializar, ao carregar o xml e substituir, são muitos campos em uma nota fiscal, por isso queria ver se tinha alguma maneira. Não ficou claro ? Editei a resposta de como eu passo os dados, para ver se fica mais claro.

Comment: Mariana, qual é o exemplo do tipo de dado, qual é a classe, explica tudo isso na pergunta, não é que não ficou claro, é que sua pergunta não explica como você faz na verdade! Coloque um exemplo da classe, e como você manipula os dados nela

Comment: É de uma classe de schema, coloquei um exemplo na pergunta, e na pergunta já havia a forma que crio, e serializo a classe. São do tipo string os dados.

Comment: `gerar` é o nome do objeto e a classe?

Comment: Você colocou a geração, mas, você não colocou um exemplo da classe! é complicado dizer se quer dinamizar o seu código fazendo com que a classe faça essa troca de caracteres para você, seja sempre objetivas nas perguntas e clara ...

Comment: Gerar é o nome do objeto, onde passo os dados serializado. A classe é enorme, pois é a classe de um xsd, se quiser que coloco ela inteira, posso colocar, mais creio que não vai resolver.

Comment: Outra coisa, se você não especificar uma solução acho eu que é uma duplicata dessa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-remover-acentos-em-uma-string porque isso já te mostra como trocar o caracteres com acentos para não acentuados.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86868/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-marianac-costa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possa ser que essa solução não seja a mais rápida, mas, resolve o problema de maneira satisfatória, porque é uma solução com reflexão (`Reflection`):

Crie uma classe que são dois métodos de extensão com a seguinte nomenclatura e contéudo?

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string RemoveAccents(this string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return string.Empty;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();            
        foreach (char letter in s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).ToCharArray())
        {
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(letter) != 
                UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            {
                str.Append(letter);
            }
        }
        return str.ToString();
    }
    public static void NoAccents<T>(this T _class) where T: class
    {
        var _properties = _class.GetType().GetProperties();
        var _fields = _properties.Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)).ToList();
        foreach (var _field in _fields)
        {
            _field.SetValue(_class, ((string)_field.GetValue(_class)).RemoveAccents());
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>***Observação:*** [exemplo de código copiado entre essas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-remover-acentos-em-uma-string) que é o código interno de remoção de caracteres com acentuação</sub>

onde em um determinado `namespace` você tem acesso aos dois métodos, um remove particularmente somente tipos do dados `string` e o outro o dado complexo `class`, exemplo:

```
public class Example
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
Example ex = new Example();
ex.Id = 1;
ex.Name = @"Relógio Henry-250\s\nDescrição 62-29\s\n";
ex.Address = "Avenída Souza Líma, 1259";
ex.NoAccents(); // aqui remove os acentos de todas as propriedades do tipo `string`
```

---

Versão também para Listas

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static string RemoveAccents(this string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return string.Empty;
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();            
        foreach (char letter in s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).ToCharArray())
        {
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(letter) != 
                UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            {
                str.Append(letter);
            }
        }
        return str.ToString();
    }

    public static void NoAccents<T>(this T _class) where T: class
    {
        void SetValueNoAccents(object valueCurrent)
        {
            var propertiesCurrent = valueCurrent
                    .GetType().GetProperties()
                    .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    .ToList();
            foreach (var field in propertiesCurrent)
            {
                field.SetValue(valueCurrent,
                    ((string)field.GetValue(valueCurrent))
                    .RemoveAccents());
            }
        }

        if(_class.GetType().GetInterfaces()
            .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && 
                t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)).Any())
        {                
            var _loop = (_class as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
            while (_loop.MoveNext())
            {   
                SetValueNoAccents(_loop.Current);
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            SetValueNoAccents(_class);
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Como faço para remover acentos em uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-remover-acentos-em-uma-string)
- [Remover acentuação](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/d86d1def-4774-4fd8-b4fc-2f57a12beb85/remover-acentuao?forum=vscsharppt)
- [Função para remover acentos em C# - ASP.NET](http://cbsa.com.br/post/funcao-para-remover-acentos-em-c---aspnet.aspx)
- [Métodos de extensão (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)
- [Como implementar e chamar um método de extensão personalizado (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method)
- [C# - Métodos de Extensão](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2820/csharp-metodos-de-extensao.aspx)
- [Para que usar métodos de extensão do C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136913/para-que-usar-m%C3%A9todos-de-extens%C3%A3o-do-c)

Comment: Resolveria o problema, porém encontrei uma maneira mais direta, e menos demorada, fiz da seguinte forma: `string RemoveAcentos(string palavacomacentos)
                {
                    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        Encoding.GetEncoding("Cyrillic").GetBytes(palavacomacentos)
                    );
                }`

Comment: @marianac_costa uma maneira direta desculpa mais isso é desconsiderar o entorno porque eu até citei as maneiras e fiz um código que resolve o problema junto com os tipos de troca de letras com acento para sem. Uma maneira rápida pode encalhar em menos código!. Se você soubesse da solução não teria dito isso.