# Estou com dificuldade em remover acentos na string

Tags: c#

Preciso tirar acentos da string.

preciso tirar para converter em URL no BD.

De á > a

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como faço para remover acentos em uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-remover-acentos-em-uma-string)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string removerAcentos(string texto)
{
    string Acentos = "ÄÅÁÂÀÃäáâàãÉÊËÈéêëèÍÎÏÌíîïìÖÓÔÒÕöóôòõÜÚÛüúûùÇç";
    string semAcentos = "AAAAAAaaaaaEEEEeeeeIIIIiiiiOOOOOoooooUUUuuuuCc";

    for (int i = 0; i < Acentos.Length; i++)
    {
        texto = texto.Replace(Acentos[i].ToString(), semAcentos[i].ToString());
    }
    return texto;
}
```